# Why is this villager not taking a job?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm trying to get the trading at max build height achievement but I brought a villager without a job without noticing. So I tried to turn him into a farmer but can't seem to get him to take the job.

Anyone know what the cause might be?

[image]

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you actually playing? You've tagged the question with both tags.

Comment: Close voting as unclear per my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Villagers sometimes can't see job-site blocks in the floor. Lower the Villager 1 block and make sure it can see both the front and the top of the composter.